# Rotate flat 2d object around an arbitrary Axis

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, matrix

So I have a flat 2d Polygon and I would like to rotate each point of the Polygon around a axis defined by two 2d Points. These rotated points are later used to generate a 3d rotations object from the flat 2d Polygon.
So I got this at the moment:

1. Calculate the axis normal position of one polygon point.
2. From this point I calculate the matrix with a matrixLookAt(pointOnLine, polygonPoint, upVec) function
3. Then I rotate the matrix on the Z-Axis with 45°
4. And finaly I multiply the polygonPoint with the computed matrix.

But with this method I don't get any usefull results.

For better unterstanding:
P1 & P2 are defining the axis
Psrc is the polygonPoint
and Pdest is the final point in 3d
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Far easier to be done. Just modify your model matrix before drawing using [`glRotatef()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
glRotatef(angle, vx, vy, vz);
```

- `angle` is obviously the angle.
- `vx`, `vy`, and `vz` are the vector defining your rotation axis.

Or, to use it with 2 points given:

```
glRotatef(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y, p1.z - p1.z);
```

If your rotation axis doesn't go through your world's origin, you'll have to adjust everything so your axis goes through the origin using [`glTranslatef()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
glTranslatef(-p1.x, -p1.y, -p1.z); // move one point on the vector into the origin
glRotatef(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y, p1.z - p1.z); // rotate everything
glTranslatef(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z); // move everything back into position
```

Comment: This would rotate the point around the center and not around the axis

Comment: Hm? How would you rotate a point around another point (the center?)? By subtracting coordinates of two points you get the dimensions of the vector between them, not the center point. Going to link documentation in the answer.

Comment: I rotate a point around a axis by creating a matrix which is moved at the normal point on the axis rotate this matrix and multiply the polygonpoint by this matrix. Like a any cad-software creates a rotationsbody

Comment: This is exactly what `glRotate()` will do - but on the graphics card: It roates all future points being drawn around the axis given by the vector (till you reset the matrix). But now that I think of it, I forgot to mention the translation, i.e. when your rotation axis doesn't go through your origin. Guess that's what you meant? Added it.